# No-op deallocator for boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost

Is there a stock no-op deallocator in Boost to use with `boost::shared_ptr` for static objects, etc.

I know it's ultra-trivial to write, but I don't want to sprinkle my code with extra tiny functions if there is already one available.

Comment: If the object need not be destructed, then why are you putting it into a shared_ptr in the first place?

Comment: Very handy if you've gone overboard with smart pointers everywhere, and you want to pass a stack or member variable to a function that requires `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: You make me think of codebases that make me cringe. :P

Comment: @Billy ONeal: if you haven't seen a codebase that makes you cringe, you haven't been in the business long enough. I've not only seen them, I've written them.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I've written them too. It helps in the care and feeding of my delete key.

Comment: The problem is that you need to know the function that takes shared_ptr won't store it somewhere to use later, as the normal promise is that the underlying is valid until the last shared_ptr is destroyed which won't be the case for your stack variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is one here:

```
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp> // for null_deleter

class Foo
{
  int x;
};

Foo foo;
boost::shared_ptr< Foo > sharedfoo( &foo, boost::serialization::null_deleter() );
```

There is, of course, a danger with the fact that you need to know the function you call doesn't store the shared_ptr for later use, as it actually goes against the policy of shared_ptr in that the underlying object remains valid until that of the last instance of the shared_ptr.

Comment: Looks like this is as close as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

Solution uses Boost.Lambda:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

int main()
{
    int *p = new int(5);

    {
        boost::shared_ptr<int> sp(p, boost::lambda::_1);
    }

    delete p;
}
```

'boost::lambda::_1' creates an empty functor that takes one argument.

You'll probably want to put a //comment in there to let people know why you did it, though.

Comment: That would fall into the *"I don't want to sprinkle my code"* category.

Comment: This solution involves more sprinkling than using a hypothetical boost::no_op_deallocator() in place of the boost::lambda::_1?

Comment: A very clever solution, but I think I'd prefer to have the trivial function somewhere and give it a descriptive name.

Comment: Well, he asked for a stock `shared_ptr` specific solution and that would be one of the possible trivial non-stock solutions.

Comment: You could also use [](void*){} now as a proper lambda.

Answer (score 2):

- If Boost `<=` 1.54, use [`boost/log/utility/empty_deleter.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/log/utility/empty_deleter.hpp).
- If Boost `==` 1.55, use [`boost/utility/empty_deleter.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/utility/empty_deleter.hpp).
- If Boost `>=` 1.56, use [`boost/core/null_deleter.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/core/null_deleter.hpp).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be cleaner just to take an extra reference so the deallocator is never called? (Although that's still not very clean.)

I can't say that there's no function in Boost which would do the job, but it doesn't sound like something they would want to include.

**EDIT:** Having read the comments and a little documentation, it boils down to this:

1. Reference leaking. At some point, execute this:

   ```
   new shared_ptr( my_global_shared_ptr );
   ```

   Advantages: conceptually easy. Disadvantages: you are leaking something on the heap.
2. Custom deallocator. Since `shared_ptr` requires little of the deallocator function, an anonymous identity function like that provided in the other answer would do fine.

   Advantages: leverages Boost and has absolutely no overhead. Disdvantages: requires a little documentation.
3. Non-static global object. If there is a global `shared_ptr` for your object, that should be the only means of access to it. Replace the declaration of the global with a `shared_ptr` intialized by `new my_class`. I think this is best.

Comment: How would you go about taking an extra reference? I didn't think `shared_ptr`s count was accessible.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I think he means copy the `shared_ptr` and store it somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, but that extra copy will be destroyed eventually. Doesn't seem very practical.

Comment: Anything is possible. `new shared_ptr( my_global_shared_ptr );` Leak it.

Comment: I prefer not to have leaks in my programs if I can help it. You're just trading one problem for another.

Answer (score 1):

There's a ticket for this on the Boost bug tracker: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1913 - no activity for a long time until some murmur two weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this what I'm using.
I use it in unit tests to adapt a local into a shared_ptr.

```
// The class NoOp_sptr_Deleter can be used to construct a shared_ptr<>()
// that will NOT delete the pointee.
// This can be helpful in unit-testing. Wrapping a local as a shared_ptr.
// Do take care with the lifetimes though.
struct NoOp_sptr_Deleter
{
    void operator()(void const *) const {}
};

template<typename T>
boost::shared_ptr<T> FakeSharedPtrFromRef(T& aRef)
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<T>(&aRef, NoOp_sptr_Deleter() );
}
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked for solutions that are already provided by Boost or the stdlib. He *knows* that it's ultra trivial to write such a function / functor.