# Question on enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the usefulness of enable_shared_from_this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this)

I want to have an idea of what shared pointers are. So, I googled and had some insight into them. And I ran into a website which provided brief overview of the smaprt pointer concept. However, I could not undesrtand what they wanted to convey with the following (or rather how to achieve it).

**Shared pointers in member functions**

Sometimes a shared pointer to the current object is needed in its member function. Boost provides a mixin template class called enable_shared_from_this, which defines a no-argument member function called shared_from_this(). It returns a shared pointer to this. At least one instance of a shared pointer to this object must exist before the first use of this method; otherwise it has undefined results (usually crash). The best way to guarantee that this is condition met is to make the constructor protected and provide a factory method that returns a shared pointer to the newly created object.

```
class Foo : public enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
public:
   void someMethod() {
      boost::shared_ptr<Foo> this_ = shared_from_this();
      // use pointer...
   }
   ...
   static boost::shared_ptr<Foo> create() {
      return boost::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo());
   }
protected:
   Foo() { ... }
   ...
};
```

Could someone please let me know how can an object of this class be created and what role does the create() method play here? (im trying to figure this out as we speak..but just in case!:))

Thanks,
Pavan,

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232712/questions-regarding-shared-from-this

Answer (score 2):

This class ("mixin") is intended for classes that you know are going to need shared access. Instead of managing the `shared_ptr`s from outside the class, this allows the class to contain this information (that it is shared using `shared_ptr`) and thus avoid some common pitfalls.

When you used a `share_ptr` for something, a common pitfall is to initialize more than one `share_ptr` with the same raw pointer -

```
Bla *bla = new Bla;
shared_ptr<Bla> x(bla);
shared_ptr<Bla> y(bla);
```

This code has a bug, the two `share_ptr`s are not aware of each other and both will `delete` the pointer. If however you use this mixin, the class itself is responsible for managing its `share_ptr`s and this makes it impossible for this bug to occur since all `share_ptr`s of an instances are derived from the same source.
This is also why you would want the constructor to be private or protected. You don't want the user to be able to create instances of the class since that will allow him to write code like the above again.
The `create` function is an entry point for you, the class writer to instantiate the class. To call `new` and pass arguments to the constructor. boost doesn't want to call `new` for you since you might want to use an allocator or use a non-trivial c'tor.