# How does enabled_shared_from_this affect the the life time of shared_ptr?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I was looking at one [page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html) of the tutorial of boost::asio.

```
class tcp_server
{
public:

  tcp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13))
  {
    start_accept();
  }

private:

  void start_accept()
  {
    tcp_connection::pointer new_connection =
      tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service()); // shared_ptr got created.
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
      boost::bind(&tcp_server::handle_accept, this, new_connection,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error)); // instance added to io_service task list, but bind does not use shared_ptr internally I believe.
  } // shared_ptr of tcp_connection goes out of scope.

  void handle_accept(tcp_connection::pointer new_connection,
  const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_connection->start();
    }
    start_accept();
  }

class tcp_connection
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
{
public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

  static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
  {
    return pointer(new tcp_connection(io_service));
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start()
  {
    message_ = make_daytime_string();
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
      boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

private:
  tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
      size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
  {
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  std::string message_;
};
```

and I found that there's one portion of run time that no `shared_ptr` object of `tcp_connection` object is alive. That seems to mean that the `tcp_connection` object would get destroyed at the beginning of that portion since the count in its `shared_ptr` goes down to zero, which is obviously not what we want.

But then I saw the comment in the class `tcp_connection` quote

> We will use shared_ptr and enable_shared_from_this because we want to keep the tcp_connection object alive as long as there is an operation that refers to it.

And I also did a search for this problem, and got a Q&A in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232712/questions-regarding-shared-from-this). But I am still puzzled by the titled question. Specifically what does it mean `there is an operation that refers to it`? At the time when `tcp_server::start_accept()` returns, all `shared_ptr` of `tcp_connection` instances should go out of scope, and probably only some raw pointer reference was added to the `io_service` task list. How does `enabled_shared_from_this` prevent the heap instance of `tcp_connection` get destroyed when there's no instances of the `shared_ptr` of this `tcp_connection` object? Or it has nothing to do with enabled_shared_from_this, but the `boost::asio::io_service` keeps `shared_ptr` of the bounded async_handler internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object is being kept alive by the functor.

Notice how the `handle_accept` callback function takes a `shared_ptr` to `tcp_connection` as an argument. The magic now happens inside the `boost::bind` call that is used for specifying the callback to `async_accept`.

That bind call returns a functor object that stores all of the arguments needed to invoke `handle_accept` *by value*. So the functor returned by bind contains a copy of the `shared_ptr` to `tcp_connection` and thus keeps it alive. The functor (think of it as a `boost::function`) is now in turn copied by the `async_accept` to allow `io_service` to perform the callback once the accept operation completes.

So the chain of ownership is: `io_service` owns the functor, which owns the `shared_ptr` which owns the `tcp_connection`. The same thing also works without `enable_shared_from_this` by the way.

Comment: Hmm, it seems the key is `bind` stores the parameters "by value" to a function object.

Answer (score 1):

This question might be answered from describing the nonintrusive design of shared_ptr, which means not touching "any" code of its pointed object.

We can get a lot of pros from its nonintrusive design. But on other hand, it leads to the situation inevitably: **once shared_ptr, shared_ptr everywhere without raw pointer.**

Let's see this snippet:

```
{
    shared_ptr<int> orig_sp{new int};
    shared_ptr<int> good_sp{orig_sp};       // it's ok
    shared_ptr<int> bad_sp{orig_sp.get()};  // leads crashing
}
```

This snippet would make your program crash because of invoking deleting twice for the same raw pointer(`new int`). The root cause is that `orig_sp` shares reference count with `good_sp` while doesn't do it with `bad_sp`. That means **you cannot create a shared_ptr from a raw pointer which has already be `shared_ptr`ed.**

Then go back to the ASIO example code. It's already well known to make the life cycle of `new_connection` longer than `tcp_server::start_accept()`'s. In this case, shared_ptr is a very useful template to prolong the life cycle accurately.

```
void handler(shared_ptr<vector<char>> buffer, /* other declarations */)
{
    // works after write.
    // buffer will be deleted automatically.
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<vector<char>> buffer{new vector<char>};

    // preparing buffer

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(*buffer),
      boost::bind(handler, buffer, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

But the problem is that a member function of a `shared_ptr`ed object wants to prolong its own life cycle.

```
class tcp_connection {
    void start()
    {
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
          boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, (/* how to fill this field? */),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
};
```

- Filling `this` in that field is unacceptable because it will not prolong tcp_connection's life cycle.
- Filling `boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection>(this)` is not acceptable too. It will cause a crash according to our first snippet.
- Perhaps `boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection>(tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service()))` looks good, but it's trying to create object itself in its member.

Now it's very clear. `tcp_connection::start()` wants to know which shared_ptr managed, but according to nonintrusive design of shared_ptr, `tcp_connection` shouldn't contain any information for shared_ptr. It's mission impossible.

At last, we have to compromise, and ask `enable_shared_from_this` for help. `enable_shared_from_this` requires that class must be derived from it by using [CRTP idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). That's why the `tcp_connection` looks so tricky.

```
class tcp_connection : boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection> {
    void start()
    {
        // ...
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
          boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
};
```

`enable_shared_from_this` template keeps some fields like reference count for shared_ptr, and provides `shared_from_this` for ones whose member functions want to use shared_ptr instead of `this`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't seem to answer the question. The problem is if boost::asio::io_service is not using `shared_ptr` to store the handler and its parameters, then all `shared_ptr` would get destroyed by the end. So it probably depends on the implementation of the asio::io_service handler implementation.

Comment: `boost::asio::io_service` uses functors to keep callback which is the return value of `boost::bind` in this case. And the functor stores `shared_ptr<tcp_connection>`. When deleting functor, shared_ptr<tcp_connection>` will be deleted too.

Comment: Ok, I know your real requirement now. Sorry for the boring answer. I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871273/passing-rvalues-through-stdbind/4871563#4871563) might be fit to you.

Comment: Yeah, that post helps. Thanks!

Comment: "you cannot create a shared_ptr from a raw pointer which has already be shared_ptred." -- false.  You cannot create two `shared_ptr` to the same raw pointer where both want to `delete` the pointer. The problem is two `ptr`s thinking they can `delete`, not two `ptr`s. If you have a different destruction code, having two `shared_ptr` to the same raw pointer is fine.  This can be a useful pattern when you have an underlying reference counted object, and you want to create a smart reference counted pointer to it, and you don't want to write or use your own intrusive smart pointer class.

Comment: Yes, your comment is much more accurate. Mine is just fit to the default shared_ptr destructor.